# Modeling attrition of customers - survival analysis?

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

I have a dataset of the following form:

```
PersonID  Factor1  Factor2  TimeActive  Attrited
   1         A      alpha      19          1
   2         B       zeta      27          0 
   3         A      gamma      4           0
```

Where each row is a person who has certain values for `Factor1` and `Factor2` (in this case two arbitrary features), and a time that they have been active. For example, person 3 started 4 months ago and has not attrited yet, but person 1 started more than 19 months ago and has attrited.

I would like to use a survival analysis-like method to forecast how long the people that are currently still active will stay active. This should take into account the values they have for Factor1 and Factor2 as well as how long they have been "alive" up until this point.

Is something like a Kaplan-Meier estimator appropriate for this kind of analysis? I have done the legwork to get my data into what I believe to be the right form, now just a bit stuck on how to analyze it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you want to use discrete time logistic regression (turn your data into person period, and predict each month survival with month as dummy variables or real variable)  or Cox.

Comment: the link provides code to do the data conversion.  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/person_period.htm. and I have found this useful http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/asa/